# How to split an array into arrays of a given size

Tags: mule, dataweave, mulesoft, mule-component, mule4

I have the input payload as below:

```
{
    "test" : ["123", "456","222","333","444","232", "222","333"]
}
```

and I need to pass these payload to another end system via the HTTP Requester. However the end system can take only five strings in the array at a time from the above array of eight strings, so I want to split the above array in to two parts based on the array size if it is greater than five in order to trigger the end system.

How to split the input array in Mule 4?

Comment: It is better to avoid asking for optimization o a better way if you don't have an initial or baseline method to compare. Ask for a solution and in case that solution doesn't perform reasonably open a new question about how to improve performance.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to loop through the array and send the request in batches of 5 you can use the `batchSize` parameter of the `foreach` scope. You do not need to add additional logic to split the array.

[image]

```xml
<foreach doc:name="For Each" collection="#[payload.test]" batchSize="5">
    <!-- paylaod here will be array of size 5 or less -->
    <!--  eg: ["123","456","222","333","444"] -->
    <!--  any additional logic / like request-->
</foreach>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the DataWeave [divideBy(n)](https://docs.mulesoft.com/dataweave/2.4/dw-arrays-functions-divideby) function which divides an array on subarrays of n or less elements.

Example:

```
payload.test divideBy(5)
```

will return

```json
[["123","456","222","333","444"],["232","222","333"]]
```

Which you can use for example as the input for a foreach. Each execution will give you as a payload an array of size 5 or less that you can use with the HTTP requester.